# Update database with a live choice made by client

Tags: php, html, jquery, sql

How to update a specific cell in phpmyadmin with jQuery after appending a specific div to a group, code is below

```
<div id="item1">Item 1
  <input type="button" value="put me in Group1" name="I1G1"> <!-- I1=Item1 / G1=Group1-->
  <input type="button" value="put me in Group2" name="I2G2">
</div><br><br>

<div id="item2">Item 2
  <input type="button" value="put me in 1" name="I2G1">
  <input type="button" value="put me in 2" name="I2G2">
</div><br><br>


<div id="Group1">Group 1</div><br>

<div id="Group2">Group 2</div><br>

<script>
    $('input[name$="I1G1"]').click(function(){
        $("#item1").appendTo("#Group1");
        $(this).hide();
        $('input[name$="I1G2"]').hide();
        <?php $UPDATE = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE results SET round = 'Group 1' WHERE team = 'Item 1'"); ?>
    });
    $('input[name$="I1G2"]').click(function(){
        $("#item1").appendTo("#Group2");
        $(this).hide();
        $('input[name$="I1G1"]').hide();
        <?php $UPDATE = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE results SET round = 'Group 2' WHERE team = 'Item 1'"); ?>
    });
//same jQuery code with 2nd item
</script>
```

the problem is when the item getting updated in database, it became always Group 2 which is the second update. So how to update the database with the selected group
on a side question is it better to use dropdown list or buttons in selecting groups

Comment: your code will never get the result you want. PHP is server side and will run before page load(so all your queries will run one after the other when your browser request the page). Javascript is client side and will run after the page is load. For what you need you have to remove the php statements frome the page and add an ajax call to php to update the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `<form>` element that uses the POST method to a php script.

```
<form id='my_form' action='my_db_script.php' method='POST'>
// form elements
</form>
```

In your php script you would use `$_POST['my_option']` to get a form option by its name... you can execute your sql in the php file.

Since you tagged jquery, you could also use the jquery onsubmit event with `$.ajax`: [(documentation)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$("#my_form").onsubmit(function() {
 $.post({
   // my options
 });
});
```

Comment: thank you but the problem is there will be 58 items needed to be appended to groups  in-order to take items in each group and add its items in subgroups